# partial view not displaying but its viewmodel works on parent

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In the cshtml code header I've instantiated a viewmodel with some data. I can bind to and display data from that viewmodel variable in the parent page. However, when I pass the viewmodel variable into a child partial view, nothing displays on the page.

```
@{
    Html.Partial("DailyReport", @DailyReportViewModel);
}
```

Any idea why the child partial view would not be displaying on the page or how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are calling the `Partial` method which return an `MvcHtmlString`, but you are not using the return value of the method.

You can do this instead

```
@Html.Partial("DailyReport", @DailyReportViewModel);
```

Razor will now render the return value from the `DailyReport` method.

Or you can use the `RenderPartial` method which render the result.

```
@{
   Html.RenderPartial("DailyReport", DailyReportViewModel);
}
```

Assuming `DailyReportViewModel` is an object of type `T` to which your partial view is strongly typed to.

Comment: DailyReport is the name of the partial view not the name of a method

Comment: When did i say it is the name of the method ?

Comment: @user7242966, as indicated by Shyju, the "at{ }" syntax creates a code block that works like a function. Html.Partial is a shortcut that you can use *outside* of a "at{ }" block to save you some trouble. Use (at)Html.Partial outside of the "at{ }" block. If you want to use it inside, use Html.RenderPartial as Shyju suggested. Sorry for the "at"...limitation of SO in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Put `@` at the front and remove the `@` from `DailyReportViewModel` and it should work.

```
@Html.Partial("DailyReport", DailyReportViewModel);
```

Comment: Razor will simply ignore the `@` when it executes the code with `@DailyReportViewModel` (as in his question). There is no difference of the output of the method when you remove this (`@`). The issue is, he is not using the return value from the method.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say to remove that one and place one at the front as in my answer.